# Prioritizing Critical CSS with PHP during a request

Tags: php, css, dynamically-generated

I've read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/), which talks about loading a web page's critical CSS first, and then asynchronously loading other CSS assets once the page has rendered.

Is it possible to use PHP to work out what must be placed in the critical asset file? To my mind, elements like input, textarea, form, table etc, can be loaded later. It's the div, ul, ol, p, hx etc that usually make up the biggest part of the "above the fold" css. Maybe always load these first?

Apart from the most important elements, I'd think the properties that make up the shape of the website are the things that must be loaded first, then the backgrounds and other "paint".

Any good ideas to start with? I'd like to generate and automatically cache the results for website pages automatically and got that all set up. I want to take it a step further with the client-side loading performance, but without too much hassle and extra time during development, while making websites for clients. The framework should do the hard work.

I thought about some smart regexes that would sort it out, but what seems so hard, is the "prioritization"..

Comment: Unless a website has hundreds of thousands of visitors a day at least, or there is some reason why it is extremely performance sensitive, I am not sure I would bother with this. Just minify and join your CSS and serve it over gzip. Out of interest, how big are your combined CSS files?

Comment: @halfer All sites are "performance sensitive". Which sites wouldn't be? Users will leave, be frustrated, etc if the site is slow. Minifying, gzipping are way more important and priority 1, sure, but that doesn't make inlining CSS up to 14kB total of no priority at all, just priority 3 when you've applied minifying, cut the unused CSS, removed JS frameworks and simplified design for performance.

Comment: @FelipeAls, thanks for your thoughts, but I don't think all sites are performance sensitive. If the OP saves a few milliseconds of load time on a site used by a small number of people, who would notice? Would it be worth the engineering effort? (+1 for the OP for the discussion though).

Answer (score 1):

Stealing the example from your [link](http://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/). You would put your main styles (div, wrappers, p, images, or any styles for above the fold) in the head to load with the normal way. Once the page loads and runs the script it fires the script to load your css files.

```
<?php
  $cssArray = array('file1.css', 'file2.css', 'file3.css');
?>
<script>
  /*!
  Modified for brevity from https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS
  loadCSS: load a CSS file asynchronously.
  [c]2014 @scottjehl, Filament Group, Inc.
  Licensed MIT
  */
  function loadCSS(href){
    var ss = window.document.createElement('link'),
        ref = window.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    ss.rel = 'stylesheet';
    ss.href = href;

    // temporarily, set media to something non-matching to ensure it'll
    // fetch without blocking render
    ss.media = 'only x';

    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(ss, ref);

    setTimeout( function(){
      // set media back to `all` so that the stylesheet applies once it loads
      ss.media = 'all';
    },0);
  }
  <?php
    foreach($cssArray as $css) {
      print 'loadCss("' . $css . '");'
    }
  ?>
</script>
<noscript>
  <!-- Let's not assume anything -->
  <?php
    foreach($cssArray as $css) {
      print '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . $css . '">'
    }
  ?>
</noscript>
```

---

From experience, and best practice, all css calls should be located in your `<head>` and all script calls should be right before your `</body>`. All files will load asynchronously to a certain number based on your web server configuration file, normally around 5. Once those files, or one is free, it starts the next file(s)

---

### Automation

This is a whole new host of problems.

1. Now you will have to load the file and have a set point to stop looking for tags, classes, or id's to check for (using an html parser).
2. Then you have to load and read your css files to pull out the classes that were found in the previous step.
3. Output the file to your filesystem in multiple files.

   - one for first load
   - others for the javascript method or load at bottom of page
4. Check the files on creation time, or modified, and remake as needed or call in if they are available

To me this option is two time consuming and can cause problems, and possibly load time decline, if not done properly or you have to process large files. Since most of this work will be done on the server, you wait to get the first byte of data will be longer then just serving them the traditional way.